# Expected CMakeLists correctly set to lib folder and compile the c file that needed to build the project, but got undefined symbol architecture

Tags: cmake, soil

Goal: Trying to use SOIL2 to simply load image in OpenGL.

Attempt:

I have tried using headers only by including the SOIL.h and then compiling SOIL.c in CMAKE but I got similar error of Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, said that It could not link to `SOIL_image_load` and `SOIL_free_image` function. Then I went on reading on SOIL2 page on guiding to use the library, then the guide said to use headers and compile the c file but since it did not work, I follow the other method which also mention in there said to use premake to build and use the `libsoil2.a` file, which i have successfully premake it and copy all the files to my lib and change my include directory to `lib/SOIL2/src/SOIL2` and make the project but then i got the following error.

Problem: Building project throws me error:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/modern-gl-sdl.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/modern-gl-sdl.dir/include/shaders/Shader.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/modern-gl-sdl
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_CFBundleCreate", referenced from:
  _SOIL_GL_GetProcAddress in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _SOIL_GL_ExtensionSupported in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_gen_mipmap_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_DXT_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_PVR_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_ETC1_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
"_CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName", referenced from:
  _SOIL_GL_GetProcAddress in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _SOIL_GL_ExtensionSupported in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_gen_mipmap_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_DXT_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_PVR_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_ETC1_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
"_CFRelease", referenced from:
  _SOIL_GL_GetProcAddress in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _SOIL_GL_ExtensionSupported in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_gen_mipmap_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_DXT_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_PVR_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_ETC1_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
"_CFStringCreateWithCString", referenced from:
  _SOIL_GL_GetProcAddress in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _SOIL_GL_ExtensionSupported in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_gen_mipmap_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_DXT_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_PVR_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_ETC1_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
"_CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath", referenced from:
  _SOIL_GL_GetProcAddress in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _SOIL_GL_ExtensionSupported in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_gen_mipmap_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_DXT_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_PVR_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_ETC1_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
"___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
  CFString in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
"_kCFAllocatorDefault", referenced from:
  _SOIL_GL_GetProcAddress in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _SOIL_GL_ExtensionSupported in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_gen_mipmap_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_DXT_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_PVR_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
  _query_ETC1_capability in libsoil2.a(SOIL2.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/modern-gl-sdl] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/modern-gl-sdl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CMAKE:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR )

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14" )

project( modern-gl-sdl )

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

find_library(COCOA Cocoa)
if (NOT COCOA)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cocoa not found")
endif()

include_directories(
    include
    lib/SOIL2/src/SOIL2
    ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

file(
    GLOB SOIL2_C
    "*.c"
)

add_executable(
    modern-gl-sdl
    src/main.cpp
    include/shaders/Shader.cpp
    ${SOIL2_C}
)

target_link_libraries(
    modern-gl-sdl
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/SOIL2/lib/macosx/libsoil2.a
    ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
    ${COCOA_LIBRARIES}
)

add_custom_command( TARGET modern-gl-sdl POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
    src/shaders
    bin/shaders )
```

The cmake runs fine when I comment out the code that used to load the image texture which is this 3 lines:

```
unsigned char *image = SOIL_load_image ( "resources/images/sexy-girl.jpeg", &width, &height, &rchanel, 0 );

glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );

SOIL_free_image_data ( image );
```

Comment: You use *COCOA_LIBRARIES* variable for link, but call `find_library(COCOA Cocoa)` sets *COCOA* variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev hmm I dont think that is the problem because the program runs fine before I added SOIL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue here helps me solved the problem

[ [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) ]

Step I do to fix my problem was:

**1. Find Library**

`find_library( SOIL2 SOIL2 lib/libsoil2.a )`

**2. Link Library**

`target_link_libraries ( modern-gl-sdl ... ${SOIL2} )`

Done that is how i fixed my problem and hope it helps other with this same kind of problem and here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(modern_gl_sdl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

find_library(SOIL2 SOIL2 lib/libsoil2.a)

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

find_package(OPENGL REQUIRED)

if(APPLE)
    find_library(COCOA Cocoa)
    if (NOT COCOA)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Cocoa not found")
    endif()
ENDIF(APPLE)

include_directories(
    include
    lib
    ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp include/Shader/Shader.cpp include/Shader/Shader.h)
add_executable(modern_gl_sdl
    ${SOURCE_FILES} include/Shader/Shader.cpp include/Shader/Shader.h)

target_link_libraries(modern_gl_sdl
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    ${SOIL2}
    ${COCOA_LIBRARY}
    ${GLEW_LIBRARY}
    ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```